# MongoDB: Parenthetical filters

Tags: mongodb, filter

How to write MongoDB find Query similar to mysql

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE userID = '1' AND name='Arun'AND (course ='Java' or course = 'Php' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either write your query straightforward using **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** for the logical OR condition on the courses as

```
db.users.find({
    "userID": 1,
    "name": "Arun",
    "course": { "$in": [ "Php", "Java" ] }
})
```

or explicitly using the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator:

```
db.users.find({
    "userID": 1,
    "name": "Arun",
    "$or": [
        { "course":  "Php" },
        { "course":  "Java" }
    ]
})
```

Both are essentially doing the same thing though the former using the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)** operator allows for a much cleaner syntax.